# MySQL: command line vs phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, command-line

I have noticed that if I ran big queries queries - such as a complex `SELECT` or a `REPAIR TABLE` - I get much faster results if I use the command line rather than phpMyAdmin. However, appreciating a graphical interface I was wandering if using `exec` to send the query directly to MySQL would speed up the exectution time and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is heavily bloated. Command line interacts with database directly. You might want to swap, if possible, to another client.

Comment: NeroS, any suggestions for such client?

Comment: Honestly, if you can do a remote connect, there's my favorite NaviCat and then SQLYog which is tad slower.